# I want to build house what plans I will need?

Tags: construction

I have Searched in internet for plans that I would need to build house 144sqm one story, I already have floor plan , thats it .

Do I need electrical plan , plumping plan , structure plan , ... ?

And usually how much does it cost to get them ? is it safe to get them from online freelancer ?

Comment: not sure exactly, but I live in Baku, Azerbaijan .

Comment: Where are you, the world is a big place.

Comment: Just mentioned in the above comment, Azerbaijan

Comment: You need all drawings mentioned above. But depends on your local, and the complexity of the project, sometimes experienced contractors may replace the speciality drawings, but there is no way (not likely) you can rely on freelancers on the internet, and expect the house to stand functioning after construction. I urge you to talk to an architect or a structural engineer immediately and expect to pay for the services.

Comment: @Gil think Sochi on the Black Sea, where the Olympics were held, follow the Caucasus mountain range all the way east to the Caspian sea, there's Baku. Azerbaijan is in the CIS and GUAM, both of which are all former Soviet states, so building codes are probably of Soviet lineage.

Comment: That changes a lot, I have no idea of the Soviet codes etc. I assume you have general contractors, if they are like here they hire all the sub trades such as carpenters, electricians, plumbers etc. giving them access to the information you will need. We can buy a new home built on our property as a single package with the general contractor  doing and being responsible for everything. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

That is a question we cannot answer in its present form Madian. You are planning on building a structure, a house, the rules and regulations are different in just about every community and this varies by country. You have a floor plan, that is great but is it buildable where you want it? You probably have zoning regulations, plumbing regulations, electrical regulations, arcketuctial regulations and a lot more. I believe you will not like my answer but I highly recommend a building contractor licensed (may not be required in all areas) in your area. Be sure the builder is responsible for all permits and all pertinent regulations. He makes his livelihood knowing and meeting these requirements. The more experience and recommendations the better. Check with several builders, at least 3. This won't be inexpensive but much more cost effective then doing it by yourself. Be sure your builder and you both understand the floor plan and what will be build. Please keep us up to date as this project progresses.

If you have a building department where you live you might visit them. People give me lots of reasons not to but it has always been a good choice for me. You can also find out who your inspectors are and talk to them about any questions, in the end they are the ones who will approve your project. You should also check if they have a performance guarantee with a penalty clause, most will not. Also you will want proof that all subcontractors have been paid. If not in our area they can put a lean on the property without ever informing the homeowner.

Comment: In fact I like your answer , very informative. I have checked where I am with several contractors but the gap in prices  between them is huge for exact same thing and requirement, I have very low expertise and knowledge in this field  so i started to worry is the expansive one use a better material and quality or he is charging so much more for the same thing ..

Comment: I am trying to find out what exactly plans I will need to build this house, Like for example i dont know if I need electrical plan or the electrical guy will just know what to do by him self as its small house and he will do whats best , stuff like this i dont know about

Comment: For contractors get recommendations from family and friends/neighbours.  Usually the most expensive and cheapest are written off, unless you have very good reason to use them, money should not be a reason.

Comment: The plans serve two purposes, it tells the contractor what you want and it tells you what the contractor is expected to do. I always have the contractor sign it and if any changes are made they must first be approved with a change order which we both sign.

Answer (score 0):

Talk to your electrical contractor for about your plan. He should have adequate knowledge of the codes and should be able to help you work out placement of the outlets, lighting, fuse box, etc.from your floor plan.
This should also work with your plumbing and HVAC contractor also.